# Sum of values by quantile

Tags: r, quantile

I have a simple question. Is there a function that generates the sum of values for a set of predetermined quantiles?

Say I have a vector example.data with 100 values

I run `quantile(example.data, seq(0,1, by = 0.1))`and I get

```
0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90% 
0.040 0.090 0.186 0.227 0.336 0.450 0.584 0.670 0.730 0.832 
 100% 
1.000
```

For each quantile I would like to see not the cut-off point, but the sum of the values for the cases in each quantile. Is there a parameter in quantile, or a similar function that includes such parameter?

Thanks much...

Comment: Something stops you from writing your own function?

Comment: How about dumping your data into `hist` ?

Comment: @ExperimenteR - not wanting to reinvent the wheel, maybe?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I got it going, Carl, thanks for offering to help...

Answer (score 2):

`quantile` gives you *quantiles*, not sums of values inside quantiles: those are fundamentally different things.

However, you can use `cut` and `split` to get the result you want:

```
q = quantile(x, seq(0, 1, by = 0.1))
cuts = cut(x, q)
values_per_quantile = split(x, cuts)
sums = sapply(values_per_quantile, sum)
```

Comment: Got the part about the function of quantile... Was only wondering if it can be extended to do an extra trick... As for your solution, it works and is super. The only thing I need to tweak now is the fact that some of the breaks are not unique. I enclosed cuts in the unique function, and it works, but I also found somewhere the suggestion to jitter the breaks. How would that work? The example code looked something like        `breaks   = c(-Inf,quantile(a[,paste(i,1,sep=".")], na.rm=T),Inf)
breaks = breaks + seq_along(breaks) * .Machine$double.eps `

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tapply(example.data,findInterval(example.data,quantile(example.data, seq(0,1, by = 0.1))),sum)
```